# Different output for pipe in script vs. command line

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have a directory with files that I want to process one by one and for which each output looks like this:

```
==== S=721 I=47 D=654 N=2964 WER=47.976% (1422)
```

Then I want to calculate the average percentage (column 6) by piping the output to AWK. I would prefer to do this all in one script and wrote the following code:

```
for f in $dir; do
    echo -ne "$f "
    process $f
done | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F "=" '{sum+=$2}END{print sum/NR}'
```

When I run this several times, I often get different results although in my view nothing really changes. The result is almost always incorrect though.

However, if I only put the `for` loop in the script and pipe to AWK on the command line, the result is always the same and correct.

What is the difference and how can I change my script to achieve the correct result?

Comment: Perhaps, this is same buffering issue. Just redirect the output to a file and then run awk on it. Or you can use cut and bc to compute the average

Comment: Try explaining problem again with some sample data as its not easy to understand what your script is doing.

Comment: Do any of your filenames contain spaces? Does your script define $dir?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Can you produce an example of the input, along with the wrong output and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing a little about what you're trying to do, and without more details it's hard to say what exactly is going wrong.

```
for f in $dir; do
    unset TEMPVAR
    echo -ne "$f "
    TEMPVAR=$(process $f | awk '{print $7}')
    ARRAY+=($TEMPVAR)
done
```

I would append all your values to an array inside your `for` loop. Now all your percentages are in `$ARRAY`. It should be easy to calculate the average value, using whatever tool you like.

This will also help you troubleshoot. If you get too few elements in the array `${#ARRAY[@]}` then you will know where your loop is terminating early.

Answer (score 0):

```
# To get the percentage of all files
Percs=$(sed -r 's/.*WER=([[:digit:].]*).*/\1/' *)

# The divisor
Lines=$(wc -l <<< "$Percs")

# To change new lines into spaces
P=$(echo $Percs)

# Execute one time without the bc. It's easier to understand
echo "scale=3; (${P// /+})/$Lines" | bc
```